# Fullpage.js adds slash between hashtag and anchor name- ng-include causes conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, fullpage.js

I use fullpage.js for a simple site and I also use angular directives. I include a .phtml file and suddenly fullpage.js anchor stops working. It adds a slash before anchor name and after #.

**UPDATE**

The problem is with ng-include. I had some ng-include in my why directive. I changed those ng-includes to directives. And It worked.

```
<div id="fullpage">
<div class="section" id="main-description">
    <div class="animated fadeIn" main-description></div>
</div>
<div class="section" id="features">
    <div features></div>
</div>
```

This is my directives:

```
app.directive('mainDescription', function () {
    return{
        restrict: 'EA',
        templateUrl: 'templates/description.html'
    }
});
app.directive('features', function () {
    return{
        restrict: 'EA',
        templateUrl: 'templates/features.phtml'
    }
});
```

While the first directive doesn't affect the anchors. The second one starts problem.

**UPDATE**

I used .php instead of .phtml and It works. But somehow I really want to know what causes the problem.

UPDATE

Well I was wrong about the .phtml file and .php. The problem was some code in my feature.phtml file.
I have another two directive inside my feature.phtml

```
<div class="bounceInLeftPart  hidden-xs hidden-sm" why></div>
<div class="bounceInLeftPart hidden-md hidden-lg" id="why-mobile" why-mobile></div>
```

This two causes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly the answer of the question. Fullpage.js has a problem with angular.js's ng-include. I changed those ng-include into custom directives and it worked.